# Magento enterprise gift registry

Tags: shipping, enterprise-1.13

Is there any option/way in Magento EE 1.13 where customer can ship gift registry item to owner's address without seeing the actual address? I am able to add item to cart from gift registry, but I only see my addresses in the checkout and not the gift registry owner's address to gift it.

I have OneStepCheckout enabled, do you think it's because of that or Magento don't allow it at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't buy default.
And you shouldn't.
[See here a detailed description of the Gift Registry concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_registry).
Usually a gift registry is opened for a specific event and is sent out to the people you know and know you.
So if you want to send the gift to some friend you should have his address :).

Technically you can get the addresses of the gift registry owner like this:
First get the customer id:  `$customerId = $model->getCustomerId()` where `$model` is an instance of the gift registry.
Then get the customer:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
```

Then get the addresses:

```
$addresses = $customer->getAddressesCollection();
```

You can try to merge in the shipping step the current customer addresses with the gift registry owner addresses or you can create a custom dropdown with the gift registry owner addresses and when you select one of his addresses, it will be like selecting 'New address' and you automatically fill in the fields with the address you selected.
I would go with the second option. This way the checkout process will go on just like it would if you fill in an address manually. It's less work and fewer risks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Well, we would like to hide the owner's address because of privacy concern. I agree we should have the address displayed in shipping address section, but I have to go with the requirement :)